# Laravel's composer.json doesn't reinstall all required packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have this Laravel composer.json that's automatically created after running composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog.

Unfortunately when I run a composer install. It's only installing 38 instead of 26 required packages.

The error message on the website is:

```
Class 'BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider' not found
```

Composer configuration:

```
{
    "name": "laravel-distro",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/installer": "^2.0.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "vendor-dir": "vendor",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Installed packages:

```
[laravel-distro &cli-image laravel-distro]php:/app$ ls vendor
autoload.php   composer       doctrine       egulias        fideloper      jakub-onderka  league         nesbot         opis           phpoption      psy            ramsey         symfony        vlucas
bin            dnoegel        dragonmantank  erusev         guzzlehttp     laravel        monolog        nikic          paragonie      psr            ralouphie      swiftmailer    tijsverkoyen

[laravel-distro &cli-image laravel-distro]php:/app$ ls vendor_backup/
autoload.php   composer       dragonmantank  fideloper      hamcrest       league         myclabs        nunomaduro     phar-io        phpspec        psy            swiftmailer    tijsverkoyen
beyondcode     dnoegel        egulias        filp           jakub-onderka  mockery        nesbot         opis           phpdocumentor  phpunit        ramsey         symfony        vlucas
bin            doctrine       erusev         fzaninotto     laravel        monolog        nikic          paragonie      phpoption      psr            sebastian      theseer        webmozart
[laravel-distro &cli-image laravel-distro]php:/app$
```

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` once. And on which environment you are running the composer install

Comment: Looks to me like the wrong environment is set (phpunit is not installed either). You're probably not requiring the `dev` part, but the normal one.

Comment: So is RUN composer install --no-dev breaking it?

Comment: @Dennis yes, if you use `--no-dev` the packages in `require-dev` won't be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be that `composer.lock` is not synchronized with `composer.json`. Try to run

```
composer install
```

and make sure you don't have message like this:

> The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json

If you do, it means someone forgot to commit `composer.lock` - the easiest solution is to run:

composer update

that will cause that all packages will be updated (it might cause some problems if something in package was changed) but it should also install all the packages that are not in `composer.lock` file but are listed in `composer.json`